# How to fix App Crashes on launch on Android

Tags: java, android, crash

I am still new to android app develop and right now i am stumble with this crashes and unable to fix

**Manifest file Details**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.outsource.ecg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.1" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ecg_mobile"
        android:label="@string/ecg_client_title" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.outsource.ecg.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/ecg_client_title" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.outsource.ecg.app.RTEcgChartActivity"
            android:label="@string/rt_ecg_chart_title" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.outsource.ecg.app.EcgLoadHistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/load_user_history_title" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.outsource.ecg.app.DeviceListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/select_device" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.outsource.ecg.app.EcgUserManageActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/user_manager_title" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.outsource.ecg.ECG_MANAGER_MANAGE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.outsource.ecg.app.CreateNewUserActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/new_user_title" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.outsource.ecg.ECG_NEW_USER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.outsource.ecg.app.EcgUserHistroyRecordActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/view_histroy_records_title" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.outsource.ecg.VIEW_HISTORY_RECORDS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.outsource.ecg.app.SDcardMountReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

</manifest>
```

Can anyone PLEASE help me with this. it is so frustrated since i can not see where can go wrong.
the point of the app is to get the ecg signal to the app, draw it and store it
 ***edit : add appEntryAdapter

```
public static class AppEntryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<AppEntry> mAppEntries;

        public AppEntryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AppEntry> entries) {
            mContext = context;
            mAppEntries = entries;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

and this is line 137 and 138 in mainActivity

```
final AppEntry entry = mAppEntries.get(arg0);
appButton.setText(mContext.getString(entry.displayNameResID()));
```

*_*-------------------------------------------------------
R.string :

```
   public static final class string {
        public static final int ID_label=0x7f040032;
```

### public static final int about_app=0x7f040001;

String.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">EcgMobile</string>
<string name="about_app">About ECG Mobile</string>
<string name="app_info">ECG Mobile\nDeveloped by:chv960@mail.usask.ca</string>

<string name="bt_not_enabled_leaving">Bluetooth is not enabled, exit!</string>


<!-- Options Menu -->
<string name="secure_connect">Connect a device - Secure</string>
<string name="insecure_connect">Connect a device - Insecure</string>
<string name="discoverable">Make bluetooth discoverable</string>

<!-- DeviceListActivity -->
<string name="scanning">scanning for devices...</string>
<string name="select_device">select a device to connect</string>
<string name="none_paired">No devices have been paired</string>
<string name="none_found">No devices found</string>
<string name="title_paired_devices">Paired Devices</string>
<string name="title_other_devices">Other Available Devices</string>
<string name="button_scan">Scan for devices</string>
<string name="title_connecting">connecting...</string>
<string name="title_connected_to">connected to </string>
<string name="title_not_connected">not connected</string>
<string name="not_connected">You are not connected to a device</string>

<!-- ECG control buttons -->
<string name="start_label">Start</string>
<string name="stop_label">Stop</string>
<string name="save_label">Save</string>
<string name="load_label">Load</string>
<string name="select">Select</string>
<string name="delete">Delete</string>
<string name="send">Send</string>
<!-- ECG user prompts -->
<string name="external_storage_unmounted_prompt">Please ensure external storage(such as SDCard) is mounted! :)</string>

<!-- Strings for Test -->
<string name="test_connection_status">Status:Disconnected</string>
<!-- Strings for Adding new ECGUser -->

<string name="add_user">New User</string>
<string name="name_label">Name:</string>
<string name="birth_label">Birth:</string>
<string name="commit_new_user_info">Save</string>

<!-- Strings for Titles -->
<string name="user_manager_title">ECGUser Management</string>
<string name="new_user_title">Create a new ECGUser</string>
<string name="view_histroy_records_title">History ECG Records</string>
<string name="ecg_server_title">ECG Mobile Server</string>
<string name="ecg_client_title">ECG Mobile Control Center</string>
<string name="load_user_history_title">ECG User History/string>
<string name="rt_ecg_chart_title">Realtime ECG Chart</string>

    <!-- Connection Status -->
<string name="connected">Status:\nConnected</string>
<string name="connecting">Status:\nDisconnected</string>
<string name="none">Status:\nDisconnected</string>
<string name="listen">Status:\nListening</string>
<string name="name_item_empty">Name is empty, please retry!</string>
<string name="create_new_user_failed">Create new user failed!</string>
<string name="male_label">male</string>
<string name="female_label">female</string>
<string name="select_valid_user">Please select a valid ecg user!</string>
<string name="not_recv_any_data">Don\'t have received any valid data, do nothing!</string>
<string name="new_user_created_debug">A new user record was created!</string>
<string name="target_device_not_connected">Target device is not connected!</string>
<string name="ID_label">ID:</string><string name="gender_label">gender:</string>
<string name="enroll_date_label">Enroll Date:</string>
<string name="age_label">Age:</string>
<string name="ecg_data_path_label">ECG DataPath:</string>
<string name="hbr_label">HBR:</string>
<string name="load_history_entry">View User History Record</string>
<string name="rt_ecg_chart">Realtime ECG Chart</string></string>
```

---------------getview of appEntryAdapter

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewGroup app_entry = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.app_entry_item, null);
            Button appButton = (Button) app_entry.findViewById(R.id.app);
            final AppEntry entry = mAppEntries.get(arg0);
            appButton.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.load_history_entry));
```

### appButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
08-12 15:01:59.763: W/ResourceType(622): Failure getting entry for 0x7f040038 (t=3 e=56) in package 0 (error -75)
08-12 15:01:59.763: D/AndroidRuntime(622): Shutting down VM
08-12 15:01:59.772: W/dalvikvm(622): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f040038
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:254)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at com.outsource.ecg.app.MainActivity$AppEntryAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:138)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-12 15:01:59.782: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 15:02:02.223: I/Process(622): Sending signal. PID: 622 SIG: 9
```

I FOUND A SOLUTION FOR THIS. BECAUSE THERE WERE 2 STRING.XML FILE (FOR SOME GOD DAM REASON I DONT KNOW ABOUT) THEY GET MIXUP BY THE IDE. WHEN I DELETE 1, IT WORKS
THANKS EVERYONE SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME OUT :)

Comment: post the code of AppEntryAdapter

Comment: `MainActivity` line 138 contains the offending code. Indeed somewhere in the `getView()` method of the `AppEntryAdapter` inner class.

Comment: post the code error is in the adapter class that u have used check line 138 of Mainactivity.java

Comment: hey post entry.displayNameResID(), what is it, up string.xml

Comment: @ mmlooloo
 <code>public int displayNameResID() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return R.string.load_history_entry;
  }
</code>

Comment: ok what is it R.string.load_history_entry in your xml?

Comment: R.string is the gen file 
-------------------------------
   public static final class string {
        public static final int ID_label=0x7f040032;
        public static final int about_app=0x7f040001;
it is just like that

Comment: no in your values folder in string.xml you defined something like load_history_entry

Comment: yes, in value folder , string.xml also include those and a few other strings as well
<string name="ecg_data_path_label">ECG DataPath:</string>
 <string name="hbr_label">HBR:</string>
 <string name="load_history_entry">View User History Record</string>
 <string name="rt_ecg_chart">Realtime ECG Chart</string></string>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clear from the log: you are trying to retrieve a String resource which isn't available. Most probably, you're using a misspelled id. Start by looking at `MainActivity.java:138` and see what string ID you're trying to get.

Also check the layout XML -- possibly you've defined some text for the view you're loading, but the string for that text does not exist in your resources.

Comment: hey. thanks for replying.
i did take a look at those line and check the string.xml
it seem fine to me since it didnt give me any warning and such. Do you know where should i look specificly ?

Comment: actually, the IDEs are pretty bad in determining errors before runtime in those xml files (like strings.xml and the different layout xmls). I would suggest having a closer look at the related content of `entry.displayNameResID()`, since it seems to be the cause. As Eran already mentioned, a misspelled id is often too easy to find (like length and lenght)

Answer (score 0):

try this, change :

```
appButton.setText(mContext.getString(entry.displayNameResID()));
```

to

```
appButton.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.load_history_entry));
```

Comment: hey. thanks for reply
i tried that but it still crash on me :(

Comment: whats the error ? post log cat again, i am going out now, and back 3 3 hrs later i will see your update, bye now !!

Comment: it is the same as previous one
08-12 02:45:26.045: W/ResourceType(515): Failure getting entry for 0x7f040038 (t=3 e=56) in package 0 (error -75)
08-12 02:45:26.045: D/AndroidRuntime(515): Shutting down VM
08-12 02:45:26.045: W/dalvikvm(515): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-12 02:45:26.055: E/AndroidRuntime(515): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 02:45:26.055: E/AndroidRuntime(515): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f040038
thanks for your help man. really appreciate it. im gonna be back after a while. 3 am here :)

Comment: hey man, this is another error about your string, the previous error has been solved because the ID of error now is different (ID #0x7f040038) , you must follow my pattern to solve these errors or else post all string.xml file and your AppEntryAdapter to tell you what is going on. if you have updated your question add comment to check !

Comment: man, thanks so much for helping me out. The weird thing is that even though i follow what you showed, It is still have the same error. I just update the string.xml
would you kindly look at that ? :)

Comment: post your log cat plus getView of AppEntryAdapter

Comment: added logcat and getview

Comment: try this: replace R.string.load_history_entry by yourpakagename.R.string.load_history_entry

Comment: I FIXED IT. I DID IT. UPDATE IN THE TOPIC. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME :)